# Go GAE Error: can't find '__main__' module (Win 8.1)

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am trying to set up Google App Engine for Go; I'm following the Google tutorial, but when I go to serve my app (goapp serve) I get the following error:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'C:\\Program Files (x86)
\\Google\\go_appengine' error while running go_appengine: exit status 1
```

I don't know if the double slashes are an issue.  My "APPENGINE_DEV_APPSERVER" env var is set as "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\go_appengine", which is where `dev_appserver.py` is located.

I'm using Go GAE 64-bit on 64-bit Win 8.1.  I have 32-bit Python 2.7 installed (as I mostly use GAE Python).   I have tried setting up my Workspace using the "How to Write Go Code" tutorial, but I'm confused about how this relates to GAE Go.  I have also created a blank "**main**.py" in the dir, and the error goes away, but the app doesn't serve a page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What instructions are you following? When you try to run go_appengine it doesn't have **main** . In order to deploy the app run dev_appserver.py

More instructions here - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/devserver

Comment: Thanks, it worked when I ran `dev_appserver.py myapp` from my workspace dir.  Could you point me to why `goapp serve myapp` gives the above error?  I was following the Hello, World! tutorial on the GAE page.

Answer (score 1):

Don't set APPENGINE_DEV_APPSERVER.

Answer (score 0):

set your PATH environment variable

APPENGINE_DEV_APPSERVER = your_go_appengine_path\dev_appserver.py

then it should work